# before save validation on vba

Tags: vba, excel, validation

i am running a data validation that will stop save if certain columns have missing data. However, it is not working. I have no idea why. Below is the code:
I will be grateful if someone can take a look.
Also, how do i filter and color-code the missing data cells for easy identification? Thank you!!!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("codes").Unprotect Password:="000"

Dim Rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MyWb As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Const rowno = 8
Const colno = 1On Error GoTo exitHandler
Set Rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
If Rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
   If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
      Else
      Application.EnableEvents = False

      Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
      Set MyWb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("codes")
      lrow = MyWb.Cells(Rows.Count, colno).End(xlUp).Row
      Start = Cells(rowno, colno)

      For i = 8 To lrow
         If IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("A" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("B" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("E" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("F" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("G" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("H" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("J" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("K" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("L" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("N" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("O" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("P" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("R" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("T" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("U" & i)) Or IsEmpty(MyWb.Range("X" & i)) Then
            Dim missdata
            missdata = MsgBox("You will need to enter topics before saving", vbOKOnly, "Missing data")
           Cancel = True
           Exit For
        End If
    End If
End If
Next i '??????
exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("codes").Protect Password:="000"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is that your code is not properly formatted. Your **`End If`** for `If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then` and `If Rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler` is in the `FOR` loop which is inside your `IF` conditions. I'm surprised you are not getting a compiler error. You also have variables that have not been declared. At the top of your code, add `Option Explicit`. Then sort out where you `IF` conditions finish. The way it's formatted just now, most of your code will never be executed

Comment: I've attempted to reformat your code by indenting it! There appears to be a problem in the 'for i = 8 to lrow` loop as there are extra `end if` statements prior to the `Next`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take a look and sort out the end if statements. Mat'sMug i used a clearer format, thanks to @RafaelMatos but the macro is not executing on save. See below for his code. I am currently not getting error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SelectedRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("codes")
    sh.Unprotect Password:="000"

    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SelectedRange = sh.Range("A8:B" & LastRow & ", E8:H" & LastRow & ", J8:L" & LastRow & ", N8:P" & LastRow & ", R8:R" & LastRow & ", T8:U" & LastRow & ", X8:X" & LastRow)

    For Each rng In SelectedRange
        If rng.Value = "" Then
            Cancel = True
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Here the code will fill de cell with color red
        End If
    Next rng

    If Cancel Then MsgBox "You will need to enter topics before saving", vbOKOnly, "Missing data"

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    sh.Protect Password:="000"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I also kept getting error messages for the if end closing but i couldnt find out where the problem is coming from. i am relatively new to VBA. @RafaelMatos Thank you so much for the corrections.  I tried the code but its doesn't seem to be working. I am not getting the error message that there is missing data.

Comment: @EbeleMaduekwe you're welcome. please, hit this answer as useful.